# Commit .xcworkspace and Pods error:pathspec

Tags: swift, xcode, git, cocoapods

I've created a new Xcode project. I've integrated Firebase and other pods as well. I'm trying to commit everything and push it to the server. (I don't use terminal but Xcode's intergraded Source code).

In the commit pop up, I see question mark signs next to the `project.xcworkspace` and the Pods folder. When I select those and try to commit them, I get the following error:

```
error: pathspec 'Pods' did not match any file(s) known to git.
error: pathspec 'project.xcworkspace' did not match any file(s) known to git.
```

How to handle this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The `Pods` directory and the `project.workspace` are added to your working directory by CocoaPods. If you want to check them in, they need to be added to your source control system.

See this [link](https://guides.cocoapods.org/using/using-cocoapods#should-i-check-the-pods-directory-into-source-control) to help you decide if you want to do that or not.